# preg_match removes escaping from json string

Tags: php, regex, json

I am trying to parse some json data using json_decode function of php. However, I need to remove certain leading and trailing characters from this long string before decoding. Therefore, I am using preg_match to remove those characters prior to decode. For some reason, preg_match is changing escaping when it encounters following substring (in the middle of the string)

```
{content: \\\"\\200B\\\"}
```

After preg_match the above string looks like this:

```
{content: \\"\200B\\"}
```

Because of this, json_decode fails.

FYI, the preg_match pattern looks like this:

```
(?<=remove_these_leading_char)(.*)(?=remove_these_trailing_char)
```

OK, so here is the additional information based on the questions being asked:

1. Why triple escaping? fix triple escpaing etc. The answer is that I don't have any control over it. It is not generated by my code.
2. The original string is not fully json compliant. It has several leading and trailing characters that need to be removed. Therefore I have to use regex. The format of that string is like this:

   returnedHTMLdata({json_object},xx);

It looks like this behavior is not limited to preg_match only. Even substr also does this.

Comment: you shouldn't have to do anything with the json_decode assuming the json data is valid to begin with.

Comment: what does your original source string look like?

Comment: See [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Now that this approach failed, you might want to elaborate why you want to strip it; why stripcslashes wouldn't work, and most importantly what the origin of the triple escaping is (magic quotes, manual sql escaping, string embedding). And fix that instead.

Comment: What is the desired result? `{content: "\200B"}`, `{content: "200B"}` or something else?

Comment: The desired result can be either the unmodified string `{content: \\\"\\200B\\\"}` or `{content: \"200B\"}`. Everything else gives a json_decode error (unexpected character)

Comment: Let me see if I got this right. You have a string like `returnedHTMLdata({content: \\\"\\200B\\\"},xx);` and you want to get the `{content: \\\"\\200B\\\"}` part of that string in order to run `json_decode` on it?

Comment: yes, you got that right. The {content...} string is only a part of json object. But that is giving me problem because of multiple backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got some [*JSON with padding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP). To remove the  function name and parenthesis, leaving the (unescaped) json object, you can do something like this:

```
$str = <<<'EOS'
returnedHTMLdata({content: \\\"\\200B\\\", foo: \\\"bar\\\", \"baz\": \\\"fez\\\"},xx);
EOS;
$str = preg_replace('/.+?({.+}).+/','$1', $str);
echo $str;
```

Output:

```
{content: \\\"\\200B\\\", foo: \\\"bar\\\", \"baz\": \\\"fez\\\"}
```

Please note that even if you manage to successfully unescape this string, `json_decode` requires that keys - e.g. "content" - are enclosed in double quotes, so you will need to modify the JSON string/object before calling that function. Or I guess you could instead use something like the old [Services_JSON](http://pear.php.net/package/Services_JSON/) package to decode it, which I believe does not have that requirement.